# How to render React.js properly - not rendering

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm trying to create a web platform where I have two pages, one is index.html, created by system and other files associated with it. There is another loginSignup.html created by me and files related to it. I used the same approach as index.html but it is rendering nothing.

Here is me loginSignup.js code :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import LoginSignup from './test';


ReactDOM.render(<LoginSignup />, document.getElementById('root1'));
```

Here is test.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './font-awesome.css'



function LoginSignup() {

    return <div>

        <form className="form-signin">
            <div className="text-center mb-4">
                <img className="mb-4" src="icon.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72"/>
                <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Assignment Submission System</h1>
                <p>Please Sign-in or Sign-up to continue</p>
            </div>

            <div className="form-label-group">
                <input type="email" id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required
                       autoFocus/>
                <label htmlFor="inputEmail">Email address</label>
            </div>

            <div className="form-label-group">
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                    <label htmlFor="inputPassword">Password</label>
                </input>
            </div>

            <div className="checkbox mb-3">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me</input>
                </label>
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-animated" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </div>

}


export default LoginSignup;
```

Inside loginSignup.html :

```
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root1"></div>
```

index.js is here :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import './font-awesome.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = '/loginSignup.html';
}, 1000);




serviceWorker.unregister();
```

It renders noting..

Comment: the noscript is telling you to do enable javascript. So you need to enable the javascript in your browser. Try using different browser. To enable JS in browser follow this link https://www.enable-javascript.com/

Comment: Have you imported ```loginSignup.js``` or set it in webpack's entry?

Comment: index.html is running properly .. it's redirecting to this page after 0.5 sec...

Comment: what are you using to build your app?

Comment: `npm start` command 

ide : webstorm

Comment: are you using create-react-app or you have your own webpack config?

Comment: `create-react-app`

Comment: can you share you index.js file?

Comment: index.js has been added...

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use either components or pure functions if you do not need lifecycle hooks.

```
class LoginSignUp extends React.Component {

   ...
   render() {
     return <div>....</div>
   }
}
```

or Pure functions

```
export const LoginSignUp = () => {}
```

Try in return use   ()

```
return (
<div>.....</div>
);
```

Comment: First of all he can use the function aswell, also you provide no explanation nor a real answer.

Comment: Where should I put it ?

Comment: This answer won't help you, it's misleading: when you want to extend the React.Component Class you first need to import it. It should work with your function LoginSetup

Comment: He imported React in first line

Comment: When you want to use the component class your import is something like: import React, { Component } from 'react';

Let him keep the functional component, it's easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I am able to compile and see in the output of your form

Your HTML layout for `<input>` is incorrect, refer the below correct JSX

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
//import "./index.css";
//import LoginSignup from "./test";
export default function LoginSignup () { /*move this portion in separate file*/

  return (<div>

      <form className="form-signin">
          <div className="text-center mb-4">
              <img className="mb-4" src="icon.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72"/>
              <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Assignment Submission System</h1>
              <p>Please Sign-in or Sign-up to continue</p>
          </div>

          <div className="form-label-group">
              <input type="email" id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required
                     autoFocus/>
              <label htmlFor="inputEmail">Email address</label>
          </div>

          <div className="form-label-group">
              <input type="password" id="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
                  <label htmlFor="inputPassword">Password</label> 
          </div>

          <div className="checkbox mb-3">
              <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"/> Remember me 
              </label>
          </div>
          <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-animated" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
  </div>)

}
ReactDOM.render(<LoginSignup />, document.getElementById("root1"));
```

export your function like the below

```
export default function LoginSignup() {
    return <div>

        <form className="form-signin">
            <div className="text-center mb-4">
                <img className="mb-4" src="icon.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72"/>
                <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Assignment Submission System</h1>
                <p>Please Sign-in or Sign-up to continue</p>
            </div>

            <div className="form-label-group">
                <input type="email" id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required
                       autoFocus/>
                <label htmlFor="inputEmail">Email address</label>
            </div>

            <div className="form-label-group">
                **<input type="password" id="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required/>
                    <label htmlFor="inputPassword">Password</label> 
            </div>**

            <div className="checkbox mb-3">
                <label>
                    **<input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"/> Remember me** 
                </label>
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-animated" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </div>

}
```

Highlighted** issues with your JSX HTML code

Comment: I have tried your code in different browser [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEGiN.png) and [also here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcWWb.png)

Comment: can you capture the console please? also you are running these on top of node right? "npm run start"

Comment: I don't understand his setup too, maybe hes doing it without node and includes react by cdn? At least this would explain the .html

Comment: Just hit localhost:3000 as it's serving response in this path